# Как правильно сказать "услуги по обслуживанию"?

Tags: языкознание

Здравствуйте. Правильно ли сказать "услуги по обслуживанию"?

Comment: @4итатель, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Правильно ли сказать "услуги по обслуживанию"?

Так говорят. См. примеры в официальном документе — [Собрании законодательства Российской Федерации](https://books.google.ru/books?id=qjYlAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8+%D0%BF%D0%BE+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E%22&dq=%22%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8+%D0%BF%D0%BE+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=f3wnVY_dMIH2sgGh5YN4&redir_esc=y).

Comment: Фраза очевидно корявая, т.к. даже в гугл буксе всего 5 вхождений найдено, причем все в одном документе. В [Русском национальном корпусе](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%F3%F1%EB%F3%E3%E0&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=2&max2=2&lex2=%EE%E1%F1%EB%F3%E6%E8%E2%E0%ED%E8%E5&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=&p=1) ситуация немного лучше: 7 вхождений, причем в разных документах 1999-2004 гг.

Comment: Ну почему же в одном? Ссылку я привёл на один только этот документ лишь потому, что он наиболее весом, входит в Собрание законодательства Российской Федерации. А примеров в Гугл-книгах значительно больше. См. 
https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8+%D0%BF%D0%BE+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8+%D0%BF%D0%BE+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E%22&tbm=bks&start=0

Comment: Простите, не заметил что поиск по одной книге. По ссылке трудно было понять.